# Adding calendar in ms access and view the data of specific day by clicking the date

Tags: database, ms-access, calendar, ms-access-2010

I'm working on MS Access, using Northwind DB. I'm trying to to add a calendar in a form and link it with the dbo_orders table. such that i can retrieve how many orders made on particular day by clicking on the date in calendar.

Ex. Consider the dbo_Orders in Northwind DB. If I click on 11/11/1996 button in the calendar it should show what all the things happened on that particular day below. i.e on the same screen having two segments, one segment above has calendar and below that should show details of that particular day upon clicking specific date.

I need to work on this, Your solution would be appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: If you narrow down your question to particular issues you come across while developing this system you will get better results.  Generally when people read "How do I make this system?" type questions, they will just skip right over it.

Comment: Thank you. I Will follow this rule. I have basic knowledge in MS Access, As i was facing problem in building the above question I thought someone would help in building the form and linking the table date to the text field to  retrieve the whole data happened on that particular day.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to tell you how to do it without telling you how to do it.

Anytime you want to capture some "event" you're going to have to write code for it (or a Macro, but I don't like 'em). Simple as that.

So, there are a number of events we can use to target this functionality. What makes the most sense, from reading your question, is the `OnChange` event for your search text box.

So, if I was going to target a text box to capture some *event*, I would view the Form in design view, right click the text box, select `Properties`, click on the `Event` tab, and select `On Change` (the `[...]` to the right side), and finally select `Code Builder`.

So, what do you want to do? You want to capture the `Text` in the text box (because select the date doesn't change the `.Value` of it, and use that essentially in the `WHERE` clause of a query (whether it's `ApplyFilter` or whatever)

In the Sub Routine for the `Text##_Change()` event, I would probably declare a `Date` variable, and do something like..

```
Private Sub Text0_Change()

Dim dateToSearch As Date

dateToSearch = CDate(Me.Text0.Text)

End Sub
```

With that variable, you can use it as a filter, use it in a query or inline SQL, or do whatever you want with it. Since you're using a split form, you can use `Me.Filter` and then apply the `Filter`.